# Django filter specific attributes from API response

Tags: django, api

I'm working with TMDB API and i want to get the specific video from a dictionary of videos that is the main trailer of a movie.

```
movie_video_request = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + str(movie_id) + "/videos?api_key=" + TMDB_API_KEY)
movie_video_results = movie_video_request.json()
movie_videos = movie_video_results['results']
newDict = dict()
for key,value in movie_videos.items():
    if key == 'name' and value == 'Official Trailer':
       newDict[key] = value

return render(request, 'Movie Details.html', {'newDict ':newDict })
```

My API response

```
"results": [
             {
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "name": "Walking Corpses Clip",
                "key": "GGe_h2MWMrs",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Clip",
                "official": true,
                "published_at": "2022-01-29T17:00:39.000Z",
                "id": "61f77629bb105700a0b16a3f"
            },
            {
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "name": "Official Trailer",
                "key": "JfVOs4VSpmA",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Trailer",
                "official": true,
                "published_at": "2021-11-17T01:30:05.000Z",
                "id": "61945b8a4da3d4002992d5a6"
            },
            {
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "iso_3166_1": "US",
                "name": "The New Spider-Man Title is…",
                "key": "iqyPvdsOWKk",
                "site": "YouTube",
                "size": 1080,
                "type": "Teaser",
                "official": true,
                "published_at": "2021-02-24T17:44:20.000Z",
                "id": "60378fdcd132d60040a45d96"
            }
    ]
```

I want my result to be that of the Official Trailer

```
{key": "JfVOs4VSpmA"}
```

so that I can place it in an `<a href>` tag

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ newDict.value }}">
  <p> Watch Trailer </p>
</a>
```

I'm getting an error

```
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closer, you will see that `movie_videos` is a list. If you want to iterate over it, just drop the `.items()`.

Later you have to change the loop a bit, because we are going through a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary of dictionaries.

It might look something like this:

```
newDict = dict()

for movie in movie_videos:
    if movie['name'] == 'Official Trailer':
       newDict['key'] = movie['key']
```

Answer (score 1):

`movie_videos` is a list of dicts not a dict.

```
for result in movie_videos:
    if result['name'] == 'Official Trailer':
        newDict['key'] = result['key']
```